Untiy Advertising Legacy v4.4, GDPR Consent Screen not appearing
Im using Untiy Advertising Legacy v4.4,
According to the documentation a conent screen should pop up for the user the first time they are shown an AD, this behavior is not happening. Any one know of there is a setting to enable this or if somthing is blocking the functionality.
Have done basic SDK initalisation, loaded up a rewarded AD, show it and no popup has appeared, just normal ad, everythign but the COnsent popup is workign fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
